# Angular + Bootstrap + Datepicker = not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using AngularJs 1.6 with angular-ui-bootstrap 2.5.0 (bootstrap-ui-tpl.min.js)

On loading the page, the model value (dateOfBirth) is not getting pre-populated in the date picker textbox. It seems, many have reported similar issues for different versions of angular/bootstrap but nothing seems to work.

HTML:

```
  <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dateOfBirth" datepicker-options="dateOptions"/>
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="openDobDatePicker()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
  </span>
```

Javascript:

```
$scope.format = 'dd/MM/yyyy'

$scope.dateOfBirth = '05/12/2004'

$scope.dateOptions = {
  maxDate: new Date(),
  startingDay: 1,
  showWeeks: false
}
```

**Edit:**
It seems angular provides `uibDateParser` to parse String to Date object. However, the following fails silently:

```
$scope.dateOfBirth = $uibDateParser.parse('05/12/2004', 'dd/MM/yyyy')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not getting populated because it's a string and not a valid `Date`. So, if you change it like,

```
$scope.dateOfBirth = new Date("05/12/2004");
```

..it would work! Also, note that `new Date(..)` will come with local timezone so in case you want to change timezone or anything regarding manipulation of dates, [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) is a great library to handle those.

**EDIT**: If your format is `dd/MM/yyyy`, you can maybe do something like this to convert in valid date:

```
var parts ='05/12/2004'.split('/');
$scope.dateOfBirth = new Date(parts[2],parts[1]-1,parts[0]));
```

Comment: I just tried as you suggested. Instead of populating 05/12/2004, it is populating 12/05/2004 in the textbox. Also, is it possible to automatically bind the date in textformat to the datePicker?

Comment: @saravana_pc not possible to bind textformat as date AFAIK. for the former, updated the answer.